# Interpretation of dimensionless numbers as ratios of forces

Tags: structural-engineering, fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering, solid-mechanics, water-resources

How can the dimensionless numbers like reynolds number etc be interpreted as ratio of the various forces? The explanation given by most sources in this regard seems quite unsatisfactory and not much rigorous. Need an explanation that is rigorous and at the same time intuitive. Here is how one book does it by defing acceleration in terms of some arbitrary length[image]

Comment: Which sources have you used? So if we quote from one, such as Stokes, or Sommerfield or Osborne Reynolds you won’t reject it? The Re is just to define 3 states of flow in a fluid: laminar, critical and turbulent.

Comment: @Solar Mike I have referred to many books that simply talk interms of  scales like length scale etc which is not that satisfying an explanation esp as a beginer . I am looking for a more basic explanation somethhing that is more satisfying and not much abstract . Do also feel free to share any such sources that may be helpful in this regard.

Comment: Gave you 3 names…

Comment: Not just unsatisfactory. For engineering purposes, it is pure crap. These are now a large class of special-purpose operators that make particular computations simpler and more compact to write. There are lots and lots of them, and most have very narrow use cases. To understand where they came from, you have to work through the derivations, and notice how the equations will magically fit on one page once the notation was sufficiently compact. Has zero to do with physics. It's about page graphics.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to derive the Reynolds equation for an example case to show how the terms for inertial and viscous force are used. Hopefully, I haven't made any gross assumptions.

---

Consider a tube of a small area of cross-section A, through which a fluid of density ρ is flowing with velocity v.

[image]

**Figure: 1-Schematic of straight pipeline with fully developed velocity profiles in laminar and turbulent flow regimes (source :[Kwame Sarkodie](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332306330_Investigation_of_the_Severity_of_Wax_Deposition_in_Bend_Pipes_Under_Subcooled_Pipelines_Conditions/figures?lo=1))**

The mass of the fluid through tube per second $\dot{m} = A\cdot v\cdot \rho$.

Using the Newton's Laws of Motion on a variable mass system, the Inertial force $F_A$ can be calculated as:

$$\dot{m} \cdot dv = dF_a$$

$$(A\cdot v\cdot \rho )\cdot dv = dF_a$$
By integrating both sides
$$F_a = (A\cdot \frac{v^2}{2}\cdot \rho )= \frac{1}{2} (A\cdot v^2\cdot \rho )$$
we could say that the $F_A$ is proportional ($\propto$) to the other quantities

$$F_A \propto A\cdot v^2\cdot \rho $$

The **viscous force $F_{v}$**, in the case of fluid flow, is represented by Newtons law,

$$\tau_x = \frac{F_{v}}{A}= μ \frac{dv}{dy}$$

where:

- A is the cross-sectional area of the tube
- $\mu$ is the viscosity (sometimes noted as $\eta$)
  and for the case above (circular tube), because of the symmetry the gradient can be approximated by $\frac{dv}{dy} = \frac{u}{r}$ or $\frac{dv}{dy} $.

Therefore, $F_{v}$ is

$$F_v = A\cdot μ \frac{v}{r}$$

Finally:

$$Re= \frac{\color{red}{\text{Inertial Force}}}{\color{green}{\text{Viscous Force}}}$$
$$Re= \frac{\color{red}{A\cdot v^2\cdot \rho }}{\color{green}{A\cdot μ \frac{v}{r}}}$$
$$Re= \frac{v\cdot \rho \cdot r }{μ}$$

where $r$ in this case is the characteristic length $L$ which is present in the other general Reynolds equation.

Comment: thanks for the answer but still the case that you have discussed ie uniform flow through a pipe of constant section how come will there be an inertial force when both local and convective accelerations will be zero? If missing something hen kindly do point that out.

Comment: The inertia force will be there as the kinetic equivalent to the viscous force. I.e. the speed across the tube will not be equal. Closer to the wall the speed will be zero due to roughness and friction. Those forces impose a kinetic change in the fluid.

Comment: "The inertia force will be there as the kinetic equivalent to the viscous force" Is there a way to visualise this? that would be much more helpful.

Comment: Think about Newton's law $\sum F = m\cdot a$. What that is saying is that all the forces acting on a body, have an effect on the particle and change its kinetic state. So you could replace all the forces with $ma$ that is kinetically equivalent. In the same sense, the viscous force is the only force acting on the fluid (if you ignore gravity) so therefore the inertia force is kinetically equivalent (its an equivalent system of forces) with the viscour force.

Answer (score 2):

The way engineers use the Reynolds Numbers - and there are now dozens, if not hundreds of them that appear in formal reports and publications, is as a computational convenience that is totally devoid of any intuitive meaning.

The original construction used an arbitrary length term. Arbitrary meaning a constant that did not in any way relate to the parameters of the thing being reported on. If you want to compare two different jibs for a 12m class sailboat, and the jibs had not one thing in common, you could do that by using the nominal 12m from the name of the boat as your arbitrary length. This became a longstanding convention. The key here is that the 12m never gets cancelled out with other terms when you perform math. It is inviolate.

But things went downhill rather quickly. Engineers started cheating. They made their own life simpler by choosing specific, non-arbitrary length terms and then letting them engage with other parameters in computations. So actual design variables started to show up in ReNs. For instance, you might select the half-span of an aircraft wing as a reference length for ReN. You can do that - as long as it is the half-span of a *different* aircraft. But no, we started using parameters for the actual part under investigation, and the math suddenly got a lot simpler. Sometimes, you would do it the otherway around, and notice that you had a bunch of parameters which you could ball up into a ReN. These things have utterly no significance in general. They are shaped like a Reynolds Number, and they are talked about as if they were a Reynolds Number, but they aren't one.

And it gets worse. For aircraft boundary layer computations, especially locating transition for turbulent transition, you actually end up *solving for the length* that will produce an appropriate ReN for transition given the flow details. This one is often designated ReX. I kept asking the instructor to please stop calling that a Reynolds Number, but they ignored me, and after a couple years, I gave up :)

Now, nothing above stops you from pulling out one of these bullshit Reynolds Numbers and studying it, and noticing that it behaves a certain way for the case at hand. The problem comes when you think that behavior is a characteristic of the Reynolds Number that can be applied to any other case that it appears in. These mistakes are continuing to cost people millions of dollars on projects that are doomed to fail. Flettner Rotor force calculations are one example. Coandra Effect forces are another. You can't equate force parameters at equal ReNs because the ReNs aren't really ReNs, they just look like ReNs.

NASAs pub files and educational videos are chock full of these engineering gaffes, I have a whole collection of them.

Comment: Just wanted to add - These bullshit ReNs appear on chart axes in thousands of serious reports. People design stuff based on these charts. But you can't because different items which evaluate to the same value will behave completely differently.

Answer (score 1):

The Reynolds number is the ratio of inertial forces to viscous forces within a fluid that is subjected to relative internal movement due to different fluid velocities.

The Reynolds number is defined as

$R_e = \dfrac{uL}{\nu} = \dfrac{\rho uL}{\mu}$

where:

- ρ is the density of the fluid (SI units: kg/m3)
- u is the flow speed (m/s)
- L is a characteristic linear dimension (m)
- μ is the dynamic viscosity of the fluid (Pa·s or N·s/m2 or kg/(m·s))
- ν is the kinematic viscosity of the fluid (m2/s).

In the opening statement, the "inertia" force indicates the resistance of any physical object to any change in its velocity, and the "vicious" force is a measure of resistance to deformation at a given rate, viscosity (μ, ν). For liquids, it corresponds to the informal concept of "thickness": for example, syrup has a higher viscosity than water.

A region where these forces change behavior is known as a boundary layer, such as the bounding surface in the interior of a pipe. A similar effect is created by the introduction of a stream of high-velocity fluid into a low-velocity fluid, such as the hot gases emitted from a flame in air. This relative movement generates fluid friction, which is a factor in developing turbulent flow. Counteracting this effect is the viscosity of the fluid, which tends to inhibit turbulence. The Reynolds number quantifies the relative importance of these two types of forces for given flow conditions, and is a guide to when turbulent flow will occur in a particular situation.

This ability to predict the onset of turbulent flow is an important design tool for equipment such as piping systems or aircraft wings, but the Reynolds number is also used in scaling of fluid dynamics problems, and is used to determine dynamic similitude between two different cases of fluid flow, such as between a model aircraft, and its full-size version. Such scaling is not linear and the application of Reynolds numbers to both situations allows scaling factors to be developed.

With respect to laminar and turbulent flow regimes:

- laminar flow occurs at low Reynolds numbers, where viscous forces are dominant, and is characterized by smooth, constant fluid motion;
- turbulent flow occurs at high Reynolds numbers and is dominated by inertial forces, which tend to produce chaotic eddies, vortices and other flow instabilities.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number

Comment: thanks for the comment. But I would like to know how in the first place do you claim that reynolds number is a ratio of inertial and viscous forces. How did you arrive at this fact? That what need to know.

Comment: More precisely how do you go from the formula rho V d /mu  to the writing the reynolds number mathematically as ratio of inertial and viscous forces ?

Comment: @inquisitivelearner so check out dimensional analysis, that will get you from the forces to that formula. Two names again: Rayleigh and Buckingham...

Comment: @Solar Mike  their works seem too mathematical and I suppose that is why posted a question here on this platform so that somebody having that power of instruction can give a more intuitive and satisfying answer in a way that is easier to understand and at the same time complete. Btw thanks for the comment.

Comment: Look at the leftmost term of the equation, the upper term involves the mass and velocity (speed) that represents the instantaneous inertia force (mass in motion), the resulting unit is identical to the lower term so cancels each other.

Comment: @r13 so you therefore mean that (mu/l) is the viscous force?

Comment: What happens when a body free flow against a body with lesser mobility? In rigid body mechanics, it results in friction and a surface roughness indicator called friction coefficient. The same can be said about fluid, but different names for the terms.

Comment: @r13 so one can write Re = rho v d/mu=(rho v/t)/(mu/d t)=Inertia force per unit volume/Viscous force per unit volume

Comment: @r13 will it be gud that way?

Comment: @r13 Also Consider the case of steady fully developed flow through a pipe of constant cross-sectional area since here will be some value of reynolds number for this flow but does that mean the inertial force for  such a flow will be any finite value other than zero? How to think or visualise the inertia force in this context?

Comment: The process of developing an equation can involve a lot of parameters, some of that can either be canceled out or left out by simplification. Without revisiting the entire process, we tend to examine the final units by rearranging them in a more meaningful way that helps to understand the equation through "implications". It is dangerous to do the reverse though - manipulate the units to fit the equation. I suggest to read the articles about the "derivation of Reynold Number" such as this one. https://www.vedantu.com/physics/derivation-of-reynolds-number

Comment: @r13 In the derivation given on the link provided by you the inertial force is evaluated for the case of  flow through a pipe of constant section with a uniform velocity v thus  as its a steady uniform flow wont the local and convective accelerations  be zero. If so then how will there be an inertial force?

Comment: Definition of **inertia** is "the tendency of a body to maintain its state of rest or uniform motion unless acted upon by an external force", once the "tendency to remain its state of rest" is breaking and uniform motion starts,, there is an implication of "force" that causes the motion/flow. Unlike F=ma, the implication of force is due to the presence of p = m*v.